# Turning off autoplay on Vimeo video that is set at a specific time to play

Tags: embed, blogger, vimeo, autoplay

I will try and be as thorough with my question as possible the first go round. My question is this:

I am trying to embed a Vimeo video on to Blogger that plays at a specific timestamp, i.e. 4mins 32secs, instead of the beginning of the video without it autoplaying. The video will embed fine at the timestamp but it will autoplay and I cannot figure out how to turn that feature off. The code for the video is below:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<br />
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="375" mozallowfullscreen=""src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/125840111#t=3665s" webkitallowfullscreen=""width="500"></iframe>
```

I have tried various methods "?autoplay=0" etc. but I guess I am not getting the code right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

have you tried like this ?

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="375" mozallowfullscreen=""src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/125840111#t=3665s?autoplay=0" webkitallowfullscreen=""width="500"></iframe>
```

if it didn't work then try to find it by inspect element, it may be changed to `?autopplay=1` after page load,
so try this method it worked for me

first your html, paste a screenshot of your vimeo video in an image tag and define an onclick function for that and bind iframe on click function,it should work 
here is the code

```
<div id="parent-div" >                                                                   
  <img id="vimeo-video" src="images/homeVideo.png" onclick="return imgClick();" />
  </div>
```

and your javascript function

```
function imgClick() {

                    jQuery('#image-for-video').hide();  //hide the image to display your video
                    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/1992892829?autoplay=0");
                    ifrm.style.width = "496px";
                    ifrm.style.height = "277px";
                    // add rest of your values
                    ifrm.frameborder = 0;
                    document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(ifrm);
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: The autoplay0 thing doesn't work in Firefox in 2018 :( Is there another way?